# Magento MAGMI: Product attributes (custom options) not showing up in import

Tags: magento, import, magmi

When importing a CSV into Magento with the MAGMI importing tool, I am unable to import Custom Options (as in size: smalee/medium/large). The import manages to put in the basic products, but the Custom Options don't transfer accross.

By custom options I mean the fields

```
Title, Input Type, Is Required,  Sort Order

    Title,    Price,    Price Type, SKU,    Sort Order
    Title,    Price,    Price Type, SKU,    Sort Order
    Title,    Price,    Price Type, SKU,    Sort Order
    and so on ...
```

Found in the custom options menu...

Even using the example CSV from the MAGMI SourceForge Wiki:

```
sku,name,description,price,Size:drop_down:1
T-Shirt1,T-Shirt,A T-Shirt,5.00,Small|Medium|Large
T-Shirt2,T-Shirt2,Another T-Shirt,6.00,XS|S|M|L|XL
```

...it fails to import the attributes.

So i'm simply using MAGMI with the supplied example data from SourceForge on a blank magento product list, and it doesn't transfer properly.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be wrong?

I am using Magento ver. 1.6.1.0 if that changes anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which errors are you getting? Did you activate the plugin?

You can activate one plugin through the Magmi web interface (way easier, go to `http://yourserver/magmi/web/magmi.php`, check it and don't forget to click on save profile before running the application) or directly editing the `magmi/conf/plugins.conf` file, adding `CustomOptionsItemProcessor` to `classes` in the itemprocessors section:

```
...
[PLUGINS_ITEMPROCESSORS]
classes = "[...,] CustomOptionsItemProcessor"
...
```

I guess the custom options plugin comes by default in Magmi. I have it installed in the folder `plugins/extra/itemprocessors/customoptions`.

Comment: No errors come up, just doesn't import custom options. I didn't know i had to activate a plugin... Is it one in in the magmi\plugins\inc folder, or one i'd download?
Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: is it the pablo_customoptions.php plugin in extra\itemprocessors\customoptions by any chance? I have tried to upload it and run again but getting the same result?